# Outgoing SOAP message encryption for WS

Tags: c#, soap, ssl-certificate, wse

I need to access a WS method by C# and one of its requirements is encrypting the SOAP message with the server's certificate public key. They sent me, for testing, that certificate, but it expired some months ago.

My questions are:

1. How can I get the server's certificate without asking them? I already tried to hook *ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback* but the method return "*A security error was encountered when verifying the message*" without accessing the callback one. Code:

   ```
   //Hook
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidationCallBack);

   //Method
   getVehicleInfoResponse = wsVehicleInfo.getVehicleInfoOperation(vehicle);
   ```
2. Would public key change in the certificate renewal or can I keep using the old one? If so, which is the way to extract and encrypt the public key from a expired certificate? Tried this by using WSE 3.0, but when I create *encDataToken* I get "*WSE511: It is invalid to use the security token SecurityToken-X now because the token is either expired or postdated.*". Code:

   ```
   secureToken = new Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityToken(certExpired);
   encDataToken = new Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.EncryptedData(secureToken); //Fails here
   requestContext.Security.Elements.Add(encDataToken);
   ```
3. Encryption algorithm must be *aes128-gcm*, but I wasn't able to find and use it. Instead I encrypt with *aes128-cbc*. Does it affect? Which is the way to select that algorithm? Code:

   ```
   [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
   public class X509TokenManager : Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenManager {
       public X509TokenManager()
           : base() {

           base.DefaultSessionKeyAlgorithm = "AES128";
       }
   }
   ```

Any help is appreciated, no need to answer mandatorily to all questions.
Thanks.

Comment: It would somewhat defeat the object of encryption if you could get the certificate without asking them for it. Why don't you just ask for an updated one?

Comment: Apart from the documentation (where it says to encrypt the message with the server's certificate public key) I didn't get the certificate, and I was getting errors in the method call. So when I asked for help, they sent me some code example, that was actually functional, in another language, aswell with the expired certificate. Since they offered to help and, over all, they are really slow replying, I wanted to find an alternative way to do it.